# How to remove space in white?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, emulation

When I select succes and development the trail screen is the one that follows but in the menu there is no such space, but from the menu to the trial page, in between these two is the masterpage

[[image]
[[image: Image Dashboard][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyyD7.png)

I want remove this space in  white, but i did not not add padding in contentpage, I dont know what to do, however I added a `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar=true`, but I cant control on top before of NavigationBar.
Also if I add padding to the contentpage it is only modified after the NavigationBar.

I've noticed if changed emulator of api 19 this space in white not exist.
[The screenshots are, on the left: 5.2 Marshmallow(6.0.0)XXHDPI Phone (Android 6.0 -Api 23) and right is: 5 Kitkat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone (Andoid 4.4 - API 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65wm.png)

this is my code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DefinityFirst.Mobile.Pages.SuccessAndDev.Dashboard"
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:DefinityFirst.Mobile.Pages.SuccessAndDev.Accordion;assembly=DefinityFirst.Mobile"
             Title="Trails"

         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="true"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:DefinityFirst.Mobile.Pages.SuccessAndDev;assembly=DefinityFirst.Mobile"

               >
  <!--<ContentPage.Padding>
  <OnPlatform x:Key="GeneralPadding2"
                        x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                        iOS="10"
                        Android="0,10,0,0"
                        WinPhone="15"/>
  </ContentPage.Padding>-->
  <!--<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="20, 40, 20, 20" Android="20, 20, 20, 20" WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>-->
  <ContentPage.Content>


    <ContentView>
      <!--CONTENEDOR TRAIL; LEVEL; PROGRESBAR-->
      <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5">
        <Frame Padding="3,1,1,2.5"  HasShadow="True" Margin="10">
          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#E1E1E1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#1F549D" Padding="5,0,0,0">
              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Padding="5,5,5,5" x:Name="stTrails" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#FF020202"  FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  x:Name="nameLevel">
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#FF020202" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                  <Image Source="mayorq.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                  <ProgressBar  Progress="{Binding ProgressLevel}"   WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="15"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  x:Name="progresBar"/>
                  <!--<control:CustomProgressBar x:Name="progressBar2" Progress=".02"  />-->
                </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </Frame>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="4,1,1,2.5">
          <Label  Text="Item List" FontSize="15.8" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Margin="10"/>
          <Picker x:Name="pickerStatusFilter"  Title="Filter by status"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="#FF020202"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <!--<BoxView/>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="50">
        <Button Text="a" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{StaticResource MainColor}" BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MainButton}" Text="b"/>
        <Button Text="c" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
      </StackLayout>-->
        <!--<StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
      </StackLayout>-->
        <!--ACCORDION-->
        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="White">
          <ScrollView>
            <ctrl:Accordion x:Name="SecOne" FirstExpaned = "true"/>
          </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>


  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Master Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="DefinityFirst.Mobile.Pages.SuccessAndDev.MasterPage"
                  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:DefinityFirst.Mobile.Pages.SuccessAndDev;assembly=DefinityFirst.Mobile"
                  NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MenuPage x:Name="menuPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator" BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainColor}">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:Dashboard/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: Use Xamarin Inspector to check what component it belongs to first.

Comment: @LexLi inspector support is disabled for an unkown reason

Comment: Inspector requires VS/XS Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this issue using a `MasterDetailPage` with the latest Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175. Both API 19 and API 23+ are not showing any extra space like shown in your images. Try the sample code from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/) and see if you have the same issue. If not, I suspect something else is wrong in the implementation of the app. An example of using the MD page:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
                  x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:ContactsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

If you can update your post with more code of how you are implementing the MDP, I will take a look and update my answer.

Comment: @A.Rodriguez, could your post with more code on how you are using the MasterDetailPage? If you can .zip the project and provide that, that might be best too. I can't reproduce the issue so I need more information from you on what you're doing.

Comment: i added the code of masterdetailpage,see the code on top

Comment: @A.Rodriguez Thanks for updating. I still can't reproduce the issue. I think I'll need a sample. You can file a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and upload a project .zip.

Comment: When I select succes and development the trail screen is the one that follows but in the menu there is no such space, but from the menu to the trial page, in between these two is the masterpage

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue and I think it might have to do with something specific to your hierarchy. Can you share how you present the SuccessAndDev page or upload a complete sample to a bug report so I can run it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too,
now i decompile xamarin,and found MasterDetailPageRenderer->SetElement(),
if sdk>=21 it set TopPadding = GetStatusBarHeight();
but i find xamarin's source,it changed.
I think will soon be modified.